# Facing js component loads very slow in application

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, tomcat

Some times one of the js file loads very slow(taking upto 5 minutes) to load the page. The js file is having a size of 1mb and which is minified one. I am using tomcat 7 server for my application. I am not able to figure out the cause for it. any one have any idea on this or faced similar kind of issue.

Comment: This issue is not causing all the times. Upon first opening the application in browser and which is reproducible in all the browsers if we clear the cache in the browser.

Comment: My Application is angular single page application and we are using grunt to load the tasks and using minify task to minify and concat all the js and html file to one file.